# Manipulate Zend_Paginator Data

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-paginator

I want to add `product variations` to my product view table which uses the Zend_Paginator.

With this code I get my products.

```
$select = $productModel->select() ... (so on)
```

With this code I create the paginator

```
$adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select);
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
```

And now I'm trying to add the `product_variations`to the product data. I was trying to do this:

```
foreach($paginator as $key => $product) {

    // get variations   
    $variations = $productModel->getProductVariants($product['ID']);
    // overwrite $product add variations
    $product['Variations'] = $variations;
    $paginator->$key = $product;

}
```

But in my view controller only the `product_data` will be shown. The array (`Variations`) is missing.

How can I handle this?

TIA
FRGTV10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this: [Adding items to a paginator already created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206337/adding-items-to-a-zend-paginator-already-created).

```
foreach($paginator as $key => &$product) {
    // get variations   
    $variations = $productModel->getProductVariants($product['ID']);
    // overwrite $product add variations
    $product['Variations'] = $variations;
}
unset($product);
```

Notice the `&` in `foreach()` - pass by reference. Then you change the referenced `$product` and don't need to assign anything back to `$paginator`.

Comment: To make it more Zend like, create your own adapter and extend getItems() method - like described here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html#zend.paginator.usage.dbselect and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146158/zend-paginator-return-as-objects (great, straight-forward example) and this is realy extremely simple.